# Выравнивание кнопок в меню по центру

Tags: html, css, меню, выравнивание

Пытался сделать меню для сайта, примерно как на изображении[image: Картинка]
Я ещё начинающий в написании сайтов. С кучей костылей был близок к желаемому меню, но никак не получается выровнять кнопки по горизонтали.

```css
#menu{
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100vw;
    font-family: tahoma;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 0%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.imgfloatl{
    float: left;
}
.imgfloatr{
    float: right;
}
#menubuttons{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100px;
}
.mbut{

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ИК</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="menu">
    <img src="./img/logoc.png" height="90%" style="padding-left: 2%; padding-right: 2%; padding-top: 1px;" class="imgfloatl">
    <img src="./img/anketared.png" height="90%" style="padding-left: 2%; padding-right: 2%; padding-top: 1px;" class="imgfloatr">
    <div id="menubuttons"><center>
        <button>Кампании</button>
        <button>Участники</button>
        <button>Деятельность</button>
        <button>Поддержка</button>
    </center></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно что-то такое сделать..

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}

#menu {
  height: 1.5em;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

#head_menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style: none;
  padding-inline-start: 0px;
  margin-block-start: 0px;
  margin-block-end: 0px;
}

.head_menu_buttos {
  height: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  align-self: center;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*margin-left регулирует расстояние между элементами списка в меню*/
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.head_menu_buttos:nth-child(1) {
  /*убираем отступ слева у первого элемента списка*/
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.head_menu_buttos:hover {
  padding: 0.25em;
  border: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}

.head_menu_img {
  align-self: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <img src="https://www.dorogavrim.ru/img/flagi/flag_svaziland.jpg" class="head_menu_img imgfloatl">
  <ul id="head_menu">
    <li class="head_menu_buttos">Кампании</li>
    <li class="head_menu_buttos">Участники</li>
    <li class="head_menu_buttos">Деятельность</li>
    <li class="head_menu_buttos">Поддержка</li>
  </ul>
  <img src="https://www.dorogavrim.ru/img/flagi/flag_svaziland.jpg" class="head_menu_img imgfloatr">
</div>
```

Comment: Можно как-то сделать расстояние между пунктами списка меньше? А ещё получается так, что у контейнера есть пробелы между его границей и границей окна, можно ли это как-то исправить?

Comment: @КВАзино Расстояние теперь регулирует `.head_menu_buttos { margin-left..` "пробелы между его границей и границей окна" Возможно у body по дефолту margin установлен, его нужно скинуть.